# How to repeat a mapping when keeping key pressed

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

I have in my `.vimrc` some simple mappings to resize split windows easily:

```
noremap <Leader><UP>    <C-w>+
noremap <Leader><DOWN>  <C-w>-
```

That works pretty fine but for example, when I want to resize the window of 10 lines I have to press and release <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> 10 times.

**How can I repeat this mapping while the keys are pressed?** What I want is when I press <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> the mapping will be applied once then after a short duration it will be applied once again and so on while I hold the keys.

*Note:* I know it is possible to prefix `<C-w>+` with a count and I could hardcode it in the mapping or simply input a count before using the mapping but that's not how I want to do it.

*Note2:* I also know that a popular mapping to resize windows is to use <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys which are easier to press several times but I don't want to use those keys to do that neither.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try entering a ... Vim [submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode)! For your case, something like this:

```
call submode#enter_with('grow/shrink', 'n', '', '<leader><up>', '<C-w>+')
call submode#enter_with('grow/shrink', 'n', '', '<leader><down>', '<C-w>-')
call submode#map('grow/shrink', 'n', '', '<down>', '<C-w>-')
call submode#map('grow/shrink', 'n', '', '<up>', '<C-w>+')
```

This means, you enter the submode with `Leader-Up` or `Leader-Down` (which will also grow/shrink the window once) and then - you'll only have to press `Up` or `Down` to grow/shrink the window, until you exit the submode.

See also the help, for timeout issues, but, to disable it:

```
"disable submode timeouts:
let g:submode_timeout = 0
```

... which means you'll stay in that submode indefinitely, until you press a key other than `Up` or `Down`, or until you hit `Esc`.

Aaand, the next useful tip I'd recommend:

```
" don't consume submode-leaving key
let g:submode_keep_leaving_key = 1
```

... which allows you to move directly to your next commands, when pressing a different key. For instance, pressing `:` will both leave the submode *and* open the command line.

Comment: I tried you solution but it doesn't seem to work: When I hit <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> I have the message `--submode: grow/shrink --` and the window is resized by one line but the command isn't repeated. I tried it with the 4 combinaisons of `g:submode_keep_leaving_key` and `g:submode_timeout` to 0 or 1. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or not. I'm usually using vim in a terminal but for now I can only test with gVim on windows but I'm not sure it change something.

Comment: The command is not auto-repeated, you still have to hit `Up` or `Down` yourself as many times as needed (but without having to press `Leader` first)

Comment: Oh I understand the code better now! It works perfectly thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer and amazing plugin! (Note: you have to install the [vim-submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode) plugin before adding the above commands to your `~/.vimrc`.)

Answer (score 4):

With [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> and resize away!

You'll use the regular hjkl keys (and maybe the arrow keys).

You can "accept" the resize or "abort" it.

There's also a move-mode where you swap windows around, and a focus-mode where you switch the window you're active in.

Comment: THIS IS INSANE! WOW!

Comment: Might I also ask you about which plugin you used to save the entire layout?

Comment: @job_start I’ve used sessions for things like that. Tpope’s obsession plugin is a great convenience for that