# How to use arrow keys mappings in vim-submode plugin on linux terminal?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

Following [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3633/1841) I've been using [vim-submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode) for some months on a windows gVim. Now that I'm trying to apply the same configuration on a terminal vim on linux I have some problems:

With the folowing lines:

```
call submode#enter_with('test', 'n', '', '<leader><UP>', '<C-w>-')
call submode#map('test', 'n', '', '<UP>', '<C-w>-')
```

<kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> let me enter in the submode `test` without any issue but in this submode when I hit <kbd>Up</kbd> I leave the submode and insert a `A` character in my buffer.

If I replace the second line with:

```
call submode#map('test', 'n', '', 'a', '<C-w>-')
```

Everything works properly i.e. hitting <kbd>a</kbd> execute the submode command.

The issue comes from the terminal which doesn't interpret correctly the arrow key because the commands works perfectly fine on a gVim on the same system.

My problem is that I don't understand why this happens because:

- The arrow key is correctly interpreted in the `enter_with` mapping. Even if I replace the first line with `call submode#enter_with('test', 'n', '', '<UP>', '<C-w>-')` hitting <kbd>Up</kbd> will trigger the submode
- I can create a mapping like `nnoremap <Up> :echo "FOO"<CR>` which will work properly.

I've tried to replace `'<UP>'` with the code of the arrow using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> to insert it which gave me `OA` but that still doesn't work.

My setup is:

> - Debian Wheezy
> - rxvt Unicode
> - vim 7.4

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: You should try `<Esc>a`.

Comment: Perhaps configure urxvt? (e.g. something like https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=71462)

Comment: @romainl: I don't understand where you think I should try `<ESC>a` I don't want to use `a` in my mapping but `<UP>`

Comment: @VanLaser: That might be a good way but I have to say that I don't understand how keycodes works. I tried to remap `URxvt.keysym.Up` but all I could do was messing the behavior of my terminal.

Comment: When you press `<Up>`, Vim doesn't receive `<Up>` but `<Esc>A` or some variant depending on your terminal emulator and/or `$TERM`. Either you map the actual escape sequence in Vim or you configure your terminal emulator so that it sends something that makes more sense.

Comment: @romainl: thanks I understand better now. I couldn't make it work by remapping in vim I'll have to find a solution to remap keys at a terminal level. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @statox - you could even try to test/use other terminal emulator (e.g. termite)

Comment: @VanLaser: The quest for the ultimate terminal is never ending ;-) I've been using gnome-terminal for a long time (before realizing how bad it is) now I've been using urxvt for some months and excepted this problem I'm pretty satisfied with it so I will keep it for a while before changing.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Make sure that [`g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave`](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode/blob/d29de4f55c40a7a03af1d8134453a703d6affbd2/doc/submode.txt#L228-L230) does not include the `<esc>` key.

Either reset it to an empty list:

```
let g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave = []
                                 ^^
```

Or double the `<esc>` key:

```
let g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave = ['<esc><esc>']
                                        ^^^^^
```

In the latter case, you'll need to press `Esc` twice to leave the submode.

Make sure to set the variable *before* invoking `submode#enter_with()` and `submode#map()`.

---

> My problem is that I don't understand why this happens

Suppose you want `<c-w>-` to be repeatable by just pressing `-`, without any plugin.  A first attempt could look like this:

```
nmap <c-w>- <c-w>-<c-w>
                  ^^^^^
```

The mapping preserves the original meaning of `<c-w>-`, and simply appends `<c-w>` in the rhs so that you don't have to press it again the next time you want to resize the window.  Note that the first `<c-w>` in the rhs is not remapped; which is why `<c-w>-` is not replaced with itself indefinitely:

> ```
> If the {rhs} starts with {lhs}, the first character is not mapped
> again (this is Vi compatible).
> For example: >
>    :map ab abcd
> will execute the "a" command and insert "bcd" in the text.  The "ab" in the
> {rhs} will not be mapped again.
> ```

See `:h recursive_mapping`.

However, something unexpected may happen if you add another mapping like `nno <c-w>i dd`.  If you press `<c-w>-` followed by a few `-`, the window will be correctly resized; but if you then press `i` to enter insert mode, Vim will instead delete the current line.

One solution is to introduce an ad-hoc prefix which – contrary to the `<c-w>` prefix – can't be typed interactively, and thus should not trigger another user mapping.  The special key name `<plug>` is a good fit for this (`<sid>` would work too; see `:h map-<sid>`).

```
nmap <c-w>- <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But this creates another issue; when you press `-` after `<c-w>-`, the window is not resized again.
You need a second mapping for your ad-hoc prefix to be able to play the role of `<c-w>`:

```
nmap <c-w>- <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
nno <plug>(prefix)- <c-w>-
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will allow you to repeat `<c-w>-` by pressing `-`, but only once.
If you want to be able to repeat `<c-w>-` as many times as desired, the second mapping needs to be recursive:

```
nmap <c-w>- <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
nmap <plug>(prefix)- <c-w>-
^^^^
```

After pressing `<c-w>-` once, as long as you press `-`, `<plug>(prefix)` will always be written in the typeahead buffer; you may see it on your command-line if `'showcmd'` is set; actually, you may see its internal representation in Vim, which is`ýS(prefix)` on my machine (`vim-submode` hides this by appending 5 no-break spaces to the prefix).

Reciprocally, as long as this ad-hoc prefix is written in the typeahead buffer, you don't have to press `<c-w>` anymore to execute `<c-w>-`, which gives you the impression of being in a submode.

In any case, that's basically what `vim-submode` does; it emulates a submode by making sure that:

- an ad-hoc and non-interactively typable prefix is always fed to the typeahead buffer
- this ad-hoc prefix can play the role of the original prefix (the one you press interactively, like `<c-w>`)

---

Getting back to your original code:

```
call submode#enter_with('test', 'n', '', '<leader><UP>', '<C-w>-')
call submode#map('test', 'n', '', '<UP>', '<C-w>-')
```

Here is a *gross* simplification of what `submode#enter_with()` and `submode#map()` do:

```
nmap <leader><up>       <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
nmap <plug>(prefix)<up> <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
nmap <plug>(prefix)     :echom 'restoring some settings, and leaving submode'<cr>
```

But `#enter_with()` also [maps escape inside the submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode/blob/d29de4f55c40a7a03af1d8134453a703d6affbd2/autoload/submode.vim#L198), with something similar to this:

```
nmap <plug>(prefix)<esc> <nop>
```

If you write these 4 lines of code in a minimal vimrc and start Vim with it, you should be able to reproduce your issue:

```
vim -Nu NONE -S <(cat <<'EOF'
    nmap <leader><up>        <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
    nmap <plug>(prefix)<up>  <c-w>-<plug>(prefix)
    nmap <plug>(prefix)      :echom 'restoring some settings, and leaving submode'<cr>
    nmap <plug>(prefix)<esc> <nop>
EOF
)
```

That is, pressing `<leader><up>` works, but `<up>` does not repeat `<c-w>-`; instead, it inserts `A` in the buffer.

Here's what happens:

1. you press `<leader><up>` which writes `<c-w>-<plug>(prefix)` in the typeahead buffer
2. Vim processes `<c-w>-` by decreasing the height of the current window; `<plug>(prefix)` remains unprocessed because there's an ambiguity (3 mappings start with this plug key), and Vim must wait until the timeout to decide what to do
3. you press `<up>` and Vim receives `Esc O A`; now the typeahead buffer contains `<plug>(prefix) Esc O A`
4. Vim expands `<plug>(prefix) Esc` into `<nop>` – which does nothing – because of the last mapping; now the typeahead buffer contains `O A`
5. Vim processes what remains from the typeahead buffer (i.e. `O A`), and opens a new line above the current line, as well as inserts `A`

It could be a Vim bug, because on linux Vim should wait 1s (provided `'timeout'`, `'ttimeout'`, `'timeoutlen'` and `'ttimeoutlen'` have their default values) to decide whether `Esc O A` is a sequence of key codes matching `<up>`, or just 3 separate keys.

It looks like [this other issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2216) where a Terminal-Job mode mapping using `<esc>` in its lhs breaks the arrow keys.

The solutions to both these issues are identical:

- either remove the mapping with `<esc>` in its lhs
- or make sure `<esc>` can't be confused with the start of a sequence of key codes produced by a special key (like `<f1>`, `<up>`, `<A-b>`...)

Note that Nvim does not seem to be affected by either of these.

---

Btw, here's an even simpler code example which suffers from the same issue:

```
nno <up>  :echom 'up'<cr>
nno <esc> :echom 'esc'<cr>
```

The first mapping works as expected by itself, but not anymore once you add the second mapping.

---

Bottom line: don't use `<esc>` in the lhs of a mapping, or, if you have to, build your lhs so that `<esc>` can never be parsed as the start of a sequence of key codes (on my machine, doubling `<esc>` seems to achieve this goal).

Knowing that, here's how you could have debug the issue.  Start by running this command:

```
:new|pu=execute('nno')
```

It should dump all your normal-mode mappings in a new buffer.  Now look for the pattern `<esc>` in the lhs of a mapping, and you should find these lines (`:v/\c<esc>/d_` may help reduce the noise):

```
n  <Plug>(submode-rhs:test:for:<Esc>) * <Nop>
n  <Plug>(submode-prefix:test)     <Esc>   <Plug>(submode-rhs:test:for:<Esc>)<Plug>(submode-leave:test)
```

Then ask Vim from where these mappings were installed, with the `:verbose` modifier:

```
:verb nno <Plug>(submode-rhs:test:for:<Esc>)
```

The answer should contain something like:

```
Last set from /path/to/vim-submode/autoload/submode.vim line 247
```

If you then look for the line 247 inside the script, you should find:

```
execute s:map_command(a:mode, s:filter_flags(a:options, 'r'))
```

From there, you just have to walk back the function calls.
The line 247 is written inside the function `s:define_submode_mapping()`, which is only called from `submode#map()`, which itself is only called from `submode#leave_with()`, which in turn is called from [`s:define_entering_mapping()`](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode/blob/d29de4f55c40a7a03af1d8134453a703d6affbd2/autoload/submode.vim#L197-L199):

```
for keyseq in g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave
  call submode#leave_with(a:submode, a:mode, a:options, keyseq)
endfor
```

And here, you can see a global variable used to configure the plugin.  If you then look at its documentation:

> ```
> *g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave*
> g:submode_keyseqs_to_leave    list of strings (default: ['<Esc>'])
> The default key sequences to leave a submode.
> ```

You should see the problematic `<Esc>` in the default value.