# Resize windows "visually"

Tags: vim-windows

When I use tmux, I can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and continue pressing any of the 4 arrow directions I want to resize a pane: I then see the pane of interest resizing while pressing and I stop when I get visually satisfied.

When I split the window in Vim, is there a similar in way to reproduce this behavior?

The closest way I found for the moment is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> (for example) but I have to re-press all these buttons over and over (while in tmux I just re-press the arrow direction and the pane resizes faster)

Comment: I think you question is a duplicate of [How to repeat a mapping when keeping key pressed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3632/1841)