# Repeat <Leader> mapping without having to press/release full combination

Tags: repeated-commands, leader

Similar to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/how-to-repeat-a-mapping-when-keeping-key-pressed) question, I want to be able to resize my splits in a repeatable manner, but without having to use a plugin. I currently use the mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>q <C-w>10<
nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w>10>
```

which works just fine. But I have to press and release the whole combination multiple times to get it to work.

Is there a simple way to make this repeatable without adding a plugin like the mentioned solution? I also use the common mapping for tabbing visually selected code:

```
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

which works by re-entering visual mode to avoid having to select again, but I'm not sure how this might be transferable to what I want to do as they aren't similar other than that I'm trying to achieve repeatability.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if nobody came up with a built-in solution for the question you linked it's because there is no plugin-less solution to do it.

Comment: You can use another count, like `5<leader>q` which will become equivalent of `<c-w>50<`.

Comment: Have a look at the various submode plugins: [Tom Links tinykeymap](https://github.com/tomtom/tinykeymap_vim/), [Kanas submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode), and [Andy Wokulas tinymode](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2223)

Comment: I'm gonna go answer that question with a favorite plugin of mine, thanks!